# Linq to Sql - FK not being generated when creating database

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Can anyone help me with the reason that a foreign key between table *Track* and table *TrackArtist* is not being generated when using the DataContext.CreateDatabase() function to create my database based on my entities?  My tables/columns generate fine, but my relationship is not being generated as a FK constraint.

I'm trying to create a FK between the tables so that the TrackArtist table can be a 'lookup' table for the Track table.

```
[Table(Name="Track")]
    public class Track
    {
        [Column (IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column]
        private int TrackArtistId {get; set;}

        private EntityRef<TrackArtist> _trackArtist;

        [Association(Name="FK_Track_TrackArtist", ThisKey = "TrackArtistId", OtherKey="Id", Storage = "_trackArtist")]
        public TrackArtist TrackArtist
        {
            get { return this._trackArtist.Entity; }
            set { this._trackArtist.Entity = value;
            TrackArtistId = value.Id;
            }
        }

        [Column (CanBeNull=false)] 
        public string Description { get; set; }  

    }

    [Table(Name="TrackArtist")]
    public class TrackArtist
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        internal int Id { get; set; }

        [Column (CanBeNull=false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the IsPrimaryKey property of ColumnAttribute is true on your Id property, the IsForeignKey property of ColumnAttribute needs to be true on your TrackArtist property.

See the MSDN documentation for ColumnAttribute.IsForeignKey here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.associationattribute.isforeignkey.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you looking for but though worth to mention. A naming convention for table key fields. I would recommend using TableNameId as primary key name. TrackId, TrackArtistId. Such naming convention should also help you find typos, which not so seldom make cryptic errors. Also, in this case of 'Id' you generally avoid conflicts with internal and protected keywords.